# Sysvol Replication issue

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, dfs-r, sysvol

I have read a lot about this recently and must say it is doing my head in.

now what I did was 6 months ago we did a upgrade of our infrastructure.

We had a 2008 R2 server for domain controller now I moved to a new system in a 2 physical hosts running 2012 and both as DC and DNS servers (the intent is 1 primary 2nd secondary ad backup)

so every thing seemed to be running fine I did the FSMO role transfers to what we will call DC1 then thinking we were done we shut down the old 2008 R2 server and we were off on our merry way.

every thing seemed to be working fine the AD had replicated the group policy's were there and every thing looked to be working. I make a change in AD for 1 server and bam that change is on the other server.

every thing was working fine till just last month I went to do some group policy changes and notice they did not replicate to DC2....

this of cause sent me on a chase the lead me to the fact the SYSVOL was not being replicated between the servers. after some searching I found this joyful TechNet KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2218556

I followed this to the letter and sadly nothing changed...

now talking to a fellow IT person he brought up a rather nasty statement...

he feels this could all have been caused by the fact I did not do a dc Demotion on the old primary DC that I am missing some vital role I needed to transfer...

now the last time this DC Server was online was 6 months ago...

now I am in the rock and hard place...

Do I hook up old DC and attempt to Demote it or is there something else I can do.

and if I do hook it up considering how old it is how much dmg will this do to my current AD.

I am hopeful with this explain you guys will be able to confirm if my fears are valid or I may just be lucky enough to be a simple fix (as simple as a IT fix can be after all lol)

Currently both Servers have error Event ID 4612

Comment: Force remove Domain Controller.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731871(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Without any debug logs its hard to say whats happening on your servers. if you have no experience looking at debug logs, please raise a case with Microsoft. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/09/dfsr-debug-log-series-wrapup-and-downloadable-copies.aspx might help

Comment: Zoredache that looks intresting but how would that help this situation. would I still hook up the old dc server then do a force demote? I have already removed the domain controller from AD users and computers..   Maweeras arh pretty dam sure what the issue is just not how to fix it. the 2 DC are sitting awaiting first replication. I just need to work out how to tell 1 of there servers they are the main domain controller and to send out the replication.

Comment: If this registry key exists, what is its value? `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\DFSR\Parameters\SysVols\Migrating Sysvols\LocalState`

Comment: @briantist In mi case the value is: 3, what do i have to do?

Comment: @x4mp73r you should post a new question with your own details. This question is over 2 years old and your environment is likely to be different. If you post a new one and leave me a link here, I will take a look at it.